# Using ADAL Angular 6 Wrapper to call API

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, adal

I followed a tutorial to build an Angular 6 app, that uses the ADAL wrapper library for angular to get a bearer-token from Azure AD and use it to call my API.

Tutorial:
https://spikesapps.wordpress.com/2017/07/27/securing-an-angular-application-with-azure-ad/

Authentication and getting the token works fine, but then I try to call my API:

```
 this.http
                .get('https://foo.azurewebsites.net/' + this.url, this.prepareOptions())
                .pipe(
                map((r: Response) => {
                    const a = r['data'] as BIExplorerSettings;
                    if (a) {
                        this.BIExplorerSettings = a;
                        this.alreadyFetchedSettings = true;
                    }
                    return a;
                }))

prepareOptions(): any {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.adal6Service.userInfo.token}`);
    return { headers };
}
```

But my app does NOT call the API under "https://foo.azurewebsites.net/". Instead it navigates to the microsoft website like:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/foo.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=xxxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx&resource=xxxxxxx-2342-xxxx-xxxx-0292xxxxxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fframe%2Fportal%2Fhome&state=a99xxxx7-xxx6-xxxc-a7b5-9xxxxx4c%7Cbceb8191-2342-4xxx-b48b-029xxxxxd4a&client-request-id=50xxxx9-fa10-xxxx-9e36-bbf9062xxxx&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.16&prompt=none&login_hint=username%40foo.com&domain_hint=foo.com

This confuses me. I only want to forward my token to my API. But for some reason the ADAL-wrapper client navigates to the microsoft page.

Any propsals why this is happening?

Comment: It should be doing that redirect in a hidden iframe. That's the way implicit grant works. But it's actually redirecting your browser?

Comment: I actually dont understand why it should even get another token at this endpoint. Actually I already have a bearer token after authentication. Shouldn't this be enough to call my API?

Comment: It should be yeah.

Comment: The call to "https://foo.azurewebsites.net/" does not even happen. I watched the traffic in fiddler and its not there... :-(

Comment: I guess ADAL somehow thinks that token is not valid for the API.

Comment: Do I have to set any permissions on Azure-Site? Maybe?

Comment: Adal package provides a built-in interceptor AdalInterceptor that prepares the http call (authentication token) for web api resources.
As a prerequisite you have to refer the web api as a resource for the angular client. In the same time the angular shall be configured with the endpoints. Here an example of how to make the necessary setup: http://www.digital-moves.eu/2018/07/19/authentication-with-azure-ad-angular-6-client-web-api

Comment: Thank you very much David. Your this example saved my day by letting me know what I was missing. I hope you were able to resolve your issue too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify if the website has access permissions for the API and the implicit flow in the manifest is true.

Answer (score 0):

microsoft-adal-angular6 If you are using angular 6 + you can use this package it is much simpler and easy to use 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-adal-angular6

More over you need to add the login and logout  redirect URL in your azure ad account in your app service